# Sending attachment with google app engine

Tags: string, google-app-engine, email, attachment, email-attachments

I'm trying to send a mail using google app engine. The app will send an email but I can not get the attachment to work. I'm trying to compile a attahment from a variable containing a string. I would like to send a .txt attachment containing the string in one of my variables. How do I send the string inside a variable as an .txt attachment with google app engine? I'm currently working with the build in webapp2 framework.

```
class send_mail(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    logging.info('Starting to send mail.')
    fileName = self.request.get('fileName')+'.txt'
    fileContent = 'some string here..'
    fileData = fileContent.encode('utf-8')
    recieve_address = 'some@gmail.com'
    attachments=[(fileName, fileData)]
    if not mail.is_email_valid(recieve_address):
      fileContent = ''
    else:
      sender_address = "admin@gmail.com"
      subject = "Mail subject"
      body = "The name off tha attachment added is: %s" % (fileName)
      mail.send_mail(sender_address, recieve_address, subject, body, attachments)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is documented here.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/attachments

If that doesn't help, please post some code and an explanation.

Comment: Hi robert. Thanks for the answer. This is the documentation I was already using. I have added some of the code above to the original post that I am using. It works fine without the attachments. But gives me an error as soon as I try to send an attachment. In the documentation it is said that the attachment data has to be a bytestring and I think this is probably still the problem. I get the following error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.

Comment: The last line of that should be:
mail.send_mail(sender_address, recieve_address, subject, body, attachments=attachments)

I verified that this should work.  The first four arguments are mandatory.  Attachments is optional, and so it is set with a keyword argument.  The documentation uses keyword arguments for all of the fields.

Comment: Thanks Robert missed that but it works perfectly now.